Persist data across multiple Wordpress shortcode calls on the same page
I am creating a custom WordPress plugin that works via shortcodes. I must call a shortcode thrice with different parameters on a single page. Each call shows parts of the data in various sections of the same page. This translates to three independent calls to the database, which bothers me because all the shortcode queries for a given page will return parts of the same row.
Is there a way to persist data across multiple shortcode calls so I don't have to query the database too often?
I have tried searching the internet, but nothing turned up.
I know that I can hack up some JavaScript, but it feels "hacky".
Thanks!
